# Tax form on iPhone Developer, non-us live in Us

Tags: iphone

I am a International student studying in US. and I am not a US citizen.
iTunes Connect assume me as a US citizen just because my address is in US.
The only form I can chose is W9 form, which is only suitable for US citizen.

Does anyone know how to solve it?  I know W8-Ben form is the right form for me, but I have no idea how do I submit online to Apple. I try to select contact us and there is no email or phone information to ask.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you should call apple (apple.com) and talk to someone directly.
or login from a different computer in your country that has a local ip address.